# Find $x$-coordinate of center of mass where $f(x,y)$ is proportional to distance from $y$-axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A lamina $D$ occupies the part of the first quadrant inside the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and below the line $y=x$. Find the $x$-coordinate of its center of mass if the density at a point is proportional to its distance from the $y$-axis.

I know the equations of the mass and moment of the lamina about the $x$-axis are $$\iint_D \varrho(x,y) dA$$ and $$\iint_D y\varrho(x,y) dA$$ respectively, and I set the bounds to $0$ to $1$ for the $x$-bounds and $x$ to $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for the $y$-bounds. However, if I compute the integral, I get a value which is undefined or $0$. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds are not correct. Density at a point is proportional to its distance from y-axis means density is $k x$ where $k$ is a constant. $k$ will get cancelled in the end when we divide moment about y-axis $M_y$ by mass $M$. So if you decide, you can exclude them from the beginning.

Also note that if we integrate wrt $dy$ first, we would need two integrals whereas if we integrate wrt $dy$ first, it would be one integral.

At intersection of $y = x$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$,

$2y^2 = 1 \implies y = 1/\sqrt2$

So, mass $M = k \displaystyle \int_0^{1/\sqrt2}\int_y^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} x ~  dx ~ dy$

or in polar coordinates,

$M = \displaystyle k \int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^1 r^2 \cos\theta ~ dr ~ d\theta$

x-coordinates of the center of mass,

$ \overline{x} = \frac{M_y}{M}$ and

$M_y =  \displaystyle \iint_D x \cdot \rho ~ dA = k \displaystyle \iint_D x^2  ~ dA$

You already know the bounds of integral for region $D$ from calculation of mass above. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: @RhysNg there are two things with your original work - first, it was for the region above $y = x$ and not below. Second, you had bounds $x = 0$ to $x = 1$ but at intersection, $x = 1/ \sqrt2$. As you were integrating for $x = 0$ to $x = 1$, you were getting zero.